# SVG - Linear Gradient independent of the shape coordinates

Tags: svg, gradient

I want to draw a svg shape with a linear gradient which is just as the gradient painted for the background. So in the example image below it should look like I paint only the blue ellipse stroke. The reason I cannot just paint the blue stroke is that the ellipse is moving in my concrete application above other objects and within the blue stroke there should not be any object but it should look like the background... With the regular definition the gradient for the ellipse is calculated according to the shape of the ellipse and by that differs from the gradient of the background ... thanks

```
<svg height="400" width="800" >
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="400" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
    <ellipse cx="200" cy="100" rx="85" ry="55" stroke-width = "10" stroke="blue" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    <ellipse cx="400" cy="300" rx="85" ry="55" stroke-width = "10" stroke="blue" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: You want it to look as if it were transparent (`fill='none'`) but at the same time you want it to be opaque to any other drawing beneath it? Is that it?

Comment: yes i guess some thing like that, thanks for looking into this - Michael's answer seems to do what i  want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use userSpace units for your gradients like so:

```
<svg height="400px" width="800px" viewBox="0 0 800 400" >
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="800" y2="400" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="800" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="400" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
    <ellipse cx="200" cy="100" rx="85" ry="55" stroke-width = "10" stroke="blue" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    <ellipse cx="400" cy="300" rx="85" ry="55" stroke-width = "10" stroke="blue" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>
```